# unable to build android project with rethinkdb java driver

Tags: java, android, rethinkdb

I tried to include rethinkdb java client driver in my android project and tried to build the project but it fails. I am using Android Studio.

This is the line in build.gradle:

```
compile (group: 'com.rethinkdb', name: 'rethinkdb-driver', version: '2.2-beta-1')
```

I get is this exception:

```
:app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception parsing classes
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:752)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:718)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$1200(Main.java:85)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$FileBytesConsumer.processFileBytes(Main.java:1645)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:284)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:672)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:574)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:311)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:277)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:245)
    at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
Caused by: com.android.dx.cf.iface.ParseException: bad class file magic (cafebabe) or version (0034.0000)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse0(DirectClassFile.java:472)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse(DirectClassFile.java:406)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parseToInterfacesIfNecessary(DirectClassFile.java:388)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.getMagic(DirectClassFile.java:251)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.parseClass(Main.java:764)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$1500(Main.java:85)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$ClassParserTask.call(Main.java:1684)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:749)
    ... 12 more
1 error; aborting
```

I tried compiling with java 1.6, 1.7 but the issue remains the same.
Gradle plugin version : 1.5.0

I have followed other SOF answers but issue still remains.

Comment: Did you try with Java 1.8? That is the minimum JVM version for the rethinkdb driver

Comment: Android does not support Java 1.8. So we can asume that the Java Driver can't be used on Android. (Which is not a good idea I think. Because you'll have to expose your database)

Comment: @dwursteisen you are correct, Java 8 is not supported in Android Studio :(

Answer (score 1):

Currently, the Java driver is only compatible with Java 8. See this blog post:

https://www.rethinkdb.com/blog/official-java-driver/

Additionally, the GitHub issue on the subject:

https://github.com/rethinkdb/rethinkdb/issues/3930#issuecomment-94911187

The primary reason is the official Java 8 requirement is lambda support. You'll probably need to ask the RethinkDB team for additional support for Java 7 (or lower) by opening a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/rethinkdb/rethinkdb/issues).

However, as Daniel suggests, you could try this Java (unofficial) driver:

https://github.com/dropbox/rethink-java-driver

Comment: The unofficial java driver specified doesn't have the change feeds feature. This makes no point to take up rethinkdb. I would go with any other nosql db.